# 9x9 bitboard implementation

Tags: java, chess, bitboard

I want to implement a 9x9 board game similar to chess, that has only rook-like moving pieces. Performance is crucial since I want to develope an AI also.

I read articles about bitboards, an efficient way to represent the game engine. There are several interesting articles about that, such as [Chess bitboard implementation in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25322531/chess-bitboard-implementation-in-java) and https://www.chessprogramming.org/Bitboards.
Of course they refer to 8x8 boards, and they apply very well to 64bit CPUs, since it allows fast bitwise operations.

In this case I need a 9x9 board, so I expect to use at least two primitive data (64 bit + 32 bit, in order to represent the 81 squares I need).

```
// 9x9 board, possible representation (64bits+32bits)
  000000000
  000000000
  000000000
  000000000
  000000000
  000000000
  000000000
  000000000
  000000000
  +15 unused bits
```

Besides the more complicated logic I will need, is it worth to use bitboards in this case? Will I actually get a good gain in performance?

Comment: "Will I actually get a good gain in performance?" This is a question we cannot currently answer as it is a COMPARISON.  A comparison to what, exactly?...your current implementation, which we know nothing about.  The best way to determine these things is to build them and test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the nicest things about bitboards and rooks is that you can precompute legal moves given a rank or file's occupancy. This is great because you can find all the legal moves without any `if` instructions. For example, let's say you isolate the current rank via shifting and masking and you get

```
10100R001
```

where 1 is an occupied square, 0 is an empty square, and your rook starts in square 3 (counting from the least significant bit, which is bit 0). Let's say you precomputed:

```
ROOK_MOVE[3][101000001] = 000110110
ROOK_CAPTURE[3][101000001] = 001000001
```

(The naive approach is good enough here because there are only 9 starting positions and 256 occupancies for the remaining 8 squares.) Then you can generate the four legal moves to squares 1, 2, 4 and 5. This requires no branching because you can extract bits one by one (for example with [Kernighan's method](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetKernighan)). To get the list of legal captures, you need to AND the second mask with the opponent's pieces on that rank.

I expect this to work well even for a 9x9 board. The extra bit handling functions should still be a lot faster than the alternative (`if`s and branching). As mentioned in the comments, the best way to find out is to test several approaches!